# Is $\text{Hom}(A,X)+\text{Hom}(A,Y)\to\text{Hom}(A,X+Y)$ always surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, abelian-groups, abelian-categories

Let $\mathsf C$ be the category of abelian groups. $A$, $Z$ two objects of $\mathsf C$, $X$, $Y$ two subgroups of $Z$. Then my question is:

> For any homomorphism $f:A\to X+Y$, can we always find two homomorphisms $g:A\to X$ and $h:A\to Y$ such that $f=g+h$?

And What if we replace $\mathsf C$ by an arbitrary abelian category, and subgroups by subobjects?

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $Z=\mathbb{Q}$, $X=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$, $Y=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{3}]$ and $A=X+Y=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{6}]$.

Then there are no non-zero maps $A\to X$ or $A\to Y$, since $X$ and $Y$ contain no elements divisible by arbitrarily large powers of $6$. So the identity map $A\to X+Y$ is not the sum of maps from $A$ to $X$ and to $Y$.

Comment: Elegant example. Thank you.

Comment: @CensiLI By the way, your question is essentially asking whether the natural epimorphism $X\oplus Y\to X+Y$ is necessarily split. If it is, then any map $A\to X+Y$ factors through $X\oplus Y$. If not, then the identity map $X+Y\to X+Y$ does not factor through $X\oplus Y$.

Comment: @CensiLI Actually, come to think of it, here's a simpler (and finite) example. Let $Z=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and let $X$ and $Y$ be the cyclic subgroups of order $4$ generated by $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Comment: Well, I've noticed the map $X\oplus Y\to X+Y$ but the constraint that the kernel should have null intersection with either $X$ or $Y$ makes me unable to think of a counterexample...

Comment: And thanks for your second example! I've never imagined it could be that simple……